# Same code, same compiler and different binary... I am very confused

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, dos, bootloader

So, my professor gave us code of example bootloader and nasm compiler...

He demonstrated how we should compile it and sent us binary after compiling it.

I came home, compiled code, started it, and... it did not work... (qemu-system-x86_64 -fda BOOT12.SYS just froze after printing "Booting from floppy", and it should have printed NP, for Not Found)

I did diff on binaries and those do seem quite a bit different...

The bottom one is mine and the top one is professors.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/f1Tb0zV.png]

Weird thin is that mine looks like it is right, since, there is quite a bit of zeros after "Boot Prog"

[image: https://i.imgur.com/C2KVdIl.png]

What do you think could be cause of something like this?

BTW, compiler is nasm 2.12 (nasm-2.12-dos.zip fea1bf6efe69446f5e6ebfae873073363e340bb6913ff5ce3658e5ea533e0dae)

I wouldn't bother you with this, but, I am very tired.

Code: https://pastebin.com/cpH11iCy

```
; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
; FAT12 sistem datoteka                                                    
; Ucitava COM ili EXE datoteku, a zatim je izvrsava (opracije LOAD i EXEC)
; Promenljiva "ImePrograma" sadrzi ime datoteke
; Zbog velicine boot sektora, greske tokom ucitavanja date su sa po dva slova:
;     "GC" za "Greska u Citanju"          
;     "NP" za "Nije Pronadjeno"           

; Radi samo sa prvom MBR particijom koja mora da bude PRI DOS particija
; sa sistemom datoteka FAT12 (ID sistema datoteka: 1)

; Radi sa disketama 360KB 5"25, 1.2MB 5"25 i 1.44MB 3"5

;                              Memorija:        segment                                                 
;                 -------------------------------------                               
;                 Tabela vektora prekida           0000                          
;                 -------------------------------                               
;                 BIOS Data Area                   0040                          
;                 -------------------------------                              
;                 PrtScr Status / neiskorisceno    0050                          
;                 -------------------------------
;                 Adresa gde se ucitava program    0060                          
;                --------------------------------                               
;                 Raspoloziva memorija             nnnn                          
;                 -------------------------------                              
;                 2KB Boot stek                    A000 - 512 - 2KB              
;                 -------------------------------                              
;                 Boot sektor                      A000 - 512                    
;                 -------------------------------                             
;                                                  A000  (granica od 640 KB)                          


;  Vrednosti registara:                  
;  --------------------               
;  DL = broj boot disk jedinice                                                  
;  CS:IP = pocetak programa                                            
;  SS:SP = programski stek (ne mesati ga sa stekom boot sektora !)          
;  COM program standardne vrednosti: CS = DS = ES = SS = 50h, SP = 0, IP = 100h        
;  EXE program standardne vrednosti: zavisi od EXE zaglavlja  
; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                          

ImageLoadSeg            equ     60h    ; U ovaj segment ucitava se kompletna slika programa sa diska
                                       ; To ne znaci da pocinje i izvrsavanje u ovom segmentu
;-----------------------
; Pocetak boot sektora 
;-----------------------
[ORG 0]
        jmp     short   start
        nop
bsOemName               DB      "BootProg"      ; 0x03

;-----------------------------------
; Pocetak BPB (BIOS Parameter Block)
;-----------------------------------

; Nazivi polja su na engleskom jeziku da bi se lakse poredili sa rezultatima upotrebe raznih alata

bpbBytesPerSector       DW      0               ; 0x0B
bpbSectorsPerCluster    DB      0               ; 0x0D
bpbReservedSectors      DW      0               ; 0x0E
bpbNumberOfFATs         DB      0               ; 0x10
bpbRootEntries          DW      0               ; 0x11
bpbTotalSectors         DW      0               ; 0x13
bpbMedia                DB      0               ; 0x15
bpbSectorsPerFAT        DW      0               ; 0x16
bpbSectorsPerTrack      DW      0               ; 0x18
bpbHeadsPerCylinder     DW      0               ; 0x1A
bpbHiddenSectors        DD      0               ; 0x1C
bpbTotalSectorsBig      DD      0               ; 0x20

;----------
;Kraj BPB
;----------

bsDriveNumber           DB      0               ; 0x24   potrebno nam je za INT 13h, fn.2
bsUnused                DB      0               ; 0x25
bsExtBootSignature      DB      0               ; 0x26
bsSerialNumber          DD      0               ; 0x27
bsVolumeLabel           DB      "NO NAME    "   ; 0x2B
bsFileSystem            DB      "FAT12   "      ; 0x36

;------------------------------
; Pocetak koda iz boot sektora         
;------------------------------

start:
        cld                     ; Kopiranje nizova bice od nizih ka visim adresama

;-----------------------------------
; Koliko je RAM-a na raspolaganju?
;-----------------------------------

        int     12h             ; BIOS poziv za velicinu konvencionalne memorije ("top" u KB)
        shl     ax, 6           ; a zatim konvertovanje u paragrafe

;------------------------------------------------
; Reervisati deo memorije za boot sektor i stek  
;------------------------------------------------

        sub     ax, 512 / 16    ; Rezervisati 32 paragrafa (512 bajtova) za kod iz boot sektora
        mov     es, ax          ; koji ce biti relociran. ES:0 -> top - 512

        sub     ax, 2048 / 16   ; Rezervisati 128 paragrafa (2048 bajtova) za boot stek
        mov     ss, ax          ; SS:0 -> top - 512 - 2048 
        mov     sp, 2048        ; Inicijalizacija SP za boot kod (dno steka je na top - 512)

;-------------------------------------------------------
; Boot kod kopira samog sebe u gornji deo memorije 
; da bi u donjoj memoriji mogao da ucita drugi program   
;-------------------------------------------------------

        mov     cx, 256          ; Kopira se 256 reci (512 bajtova)
        mov     si, 7C00h        
        xor     di, di           ; ES:DI -> pocetak odredisnog niza (ES:0 = top - 512)
        mov     ds, di           ; DS:SI -> pocetak izvornog niza (0:7C00h)
        rep     movsw            ; Kopiraj 512 bajtova

;----------------------------------------
; Predaja kontrole relociranom boot kodu
;----------------------------------------

        push    es               ; Ovaj deo boot koda sada je relociran ali ga jos uvek izvrsavamo
        push    word main        ; u nerelociranom delu. Tekuca vrednost ES (segment gde smo kopirali
        retf                     ; kod sa lokacije 0:7C00h) je buduca vrednost CS.

main:                            ; Sada nastavljamo izvrsavanje u relociranom boot kodu. 
        push    cs
        pop     ds               ; DS=CS jer je program svega 512 bajtova

        mov     [bsDriveNumber], dl     ; Sacuvati broj boot diska (npr. floppy A = 00, B = 01, prvi HDD = 080h...)
                                        ; Ovo smo dobili kao zaostatak nakon BIOS INT 19h - load boot sector.
                                        ; INT 19h prekidna rutina cita ovaj podatak iz CMOS RAM-a, Flash-a
                                        ; ili druge vrste memorije gde se cuvaju podaci za BIOS.
                                        ; INT 19h prekidna rutina, nakon upotrebe, broj diska ostavlja u DL.
;------------------------------------------
; Rezervisati memoriju za smestanje FAT12 
;------------------------------------------

        mov     ax, [bpbBytesPerSector]
        shr     ax, 4                    ; AX = velicina sektora u paragrafima
        mov     cx, [bpbSectorsPerFAT]   ; CX = velicina FAT u sektorima
        mul     cx                       ; AX = velicina FAT u paragrafima

        mov     di, ss                   ; FAT bafer se nalazi odmah iza steka  
        sub     di, ax                  
        mov     es, di                   ; ES:BX -> bafer za FAT 
        xor     bx, bx                   ; Pocetak bafera = ES:0 -> (top - 512 - 2048 - velicina FAT) 

        mov     ax, [bpbHiddenSectors]   ; Preskociti sakrivene i rezervisane sektore
        mov     dx, [bpbHiddenSectors+2]
        add     ax, [bpbReservedSectors] ; Boot sektor
        adc     dx, bx                   ; DX:AX = Linear Block Address (LBA) prvog sektora prve FAT  

        call    CitajSektor              ; Citati CX sektora prve FAT


;----------------------------------------------------------------
; Rezervisati memoriju za root direktorijum, a zatim ga ucitati   
;----------------------------------------------------------------

        mov     bx, ax
        mov     di, dx                   ; Sacuvati LBA prvog sektora prve FAT u DI:BX          

        mov     ax, 32                   ; Jedna direktorjumska stavka ima 32 bajta
        mov     si, [bpbRootEntries]     ; Broj direktorijumskih stavki
        mul     si                       ; Broj bajtova za direktorijum 
        div     word [bpbBytesPerSector]
        mov     cx, ax                   ; CX = velicina root direktorijuma u sektorima

        mov     al, [bpbNumberOfFATs]    ; Broj FAT tabela (standardno 2)
        cbw                              ; Konverovati sadrzaj AL u AX Word
        mul     word [bpbSectorsPerFAT]  ; Ukupan broj sektora za sve FAT
        add     ax, bx                   ; Dodati na LBA prvog sektora FAT
        adc     dx, di                   ; DX:AX = LBA prvog sektora root direktorijuma

        push    es                       ; Segment FAT bafera na stek (drugi parametar - WORD) 
        push    word ImageLoadSeg        
        pop     es                       ; Segment pocetka bafera za root direktorijum (060h)
        xor     bx, bx                   ; ES:BX -> bafer za root direktorijum

        call    CitajSektor              ; Citanje CX sektora root direktorijuma

        add     ax, cx                   ; Dodati broj sektora za root direktorijum na LBA
        adc     dx, bx                   ; podesiti LBA na prvi klaster oblasti podataka  
                                         ; (LBA_klastera_2)
        push    dx
        push    ax                       ; LBA_klastera_2 na stek (prvi parametar - DWORD)    

;--------------------------------------------------------------
; Potraziti COM ili EXE program kojeg treba ucitati i izvrsiti
;--------------------------------------------------------------

        mov     di, bx                  ; ES:DI -> tekuca stavka iz root direktorijuma
        mov     dx, si                  ; DX = broj stavki u direktorijumu
        mov     si, ImePrograma         ; DS:SI -> ime programa

;---------------------------------------------------
; Trazimo datoteku sa zadatim imenom
;---------------------------------------------------
; Ulaz:  DS:SI -> ime datoteke (11 znakova, tj 8+3)
;        ES:DI -> polje root direktorijuma
;        DX = broj stavki u root direktorijumu
; Izlaz: SI = redni broj prvog klastera datoteke          
;---------------------------------------------------

        mov     cx, 11                  ; CL = broj znakova u imenu (DOS 8+3). CH = 0.
NadjiIme:                               ; Ime je prvo polje od 11 bajtova u dir. stavci
        cmp     byte [es:di], ch        ; Pocetak tekuce direktorijumske stavke je [ES:DI]
        je      ImeNijeNadjeno          ; Kraj direktorijuma. Prvi bajt imena je 0 (nedodeljeno).
        pusha
        repe    cmpsb                   ; Ova instrikcija poredi [DS:SI] sa [ES:DI] 
        popa                            ; Poredi se CX bajtova, pri cemu se CX ne menja
        je      ImeNadjeno              ; Ako je svih CX bajtova medjusobno jednako, ZF=1
        add     di, 32                  ; Sledeca stavka u root direktorijumu
        dec     dx                      ; Da li je u pitanju poslednja stavka direktorijuma?
        jnz     NadjiIme                ; Ako nije, tazi dalje.
ImeNijeNadjeno:
        jmp     GreskaNP
ImeNadjeno:                             ; Pronasli smo trazeno ime datoteke.
        mov     si, [es:di+1Ah]         ; SI = redni broj prvog klastera (start).
                                        ; Ovo je bajt br. 26 u direktorijumskoj stavci.
;----------------------------
; Ucitati kompletni program
;----------------------------

CitajSledeciKlaster:
        call    CitajKlaster
        cmp     si, 0FF8h               ; EOC (End of Chain) moze da bude od 0FF8h do 0FFFh
        jc      CitajSledeciKlaster     ; Ovim se ispituje da li je SI manje od EOC. Ako jeste,
                                        ; ucitava se sledeci klaster.
;--------------------------------
; Ispitivanje tipa (COM ili EXE)
;--------------------------------

        cli                             ; Prlikom raznih podesavanja steka ne sme da dodje do prekida
        mov     ax, ImageLoadSeg
        mov     es, ax
        cmp     word [es:0], 5A4Dh      ; Da li su pva dva bajta "MZ"?
        je      RelocirajEXE            ; Ako jesu, to je EXE program

;-------------------------
; Startovati COM program              
;-------------------------

        mov     ax, es                 
        sub     ax, 10h                ; Treba oduzeti 10h od svih segmentnih registara da bi se
        mov     es, ax                 ; u memoriji napravio prostor za PSP (memorijska struktura velicine 100h
        mov     ds, ax                 ; koju kreira DOS nakon ucitavanja, a pre izvrsavanja programa).
        mov     ss, ax                 ; Mi ne koristimo PSP, ali moramo da uzmemo u obzir memoriju koju zauzima.*
        xor     sp, sp                 ; SP se inicijalizuje na 0000. Zbog osobine 16-bitnog broja (wrap around)
                                       ; prvi PUSH pomera SP na FFFE, tj. na vrh memorijskog segmenta od 64K.
        push    es                     ; Ovaj sadrzaj ES bice vrednost CS nakon izvrsavanja instrukcije RETF.
        push    word 100h              ; Nakon instrukcije RETF, IP se inicijalizuje na 100h.
        jmp     Run                    ; U propratnom materijalu objasnjeno je zasto se ovako predaje kontrola.

; (*) Napomena. Ukoliko ne zelimo kompatibilnost sa MS-DOS-om, mozemo da izostavimo PSP. 
;               Tada ne treba za njega rezervisati prostor (treba izbaciti sub ax, 10h), 
;               inicijalnu vrednost IP treba posaviti na 0 ('push word 0h' umesto 'push word 100h'), 
;               a nasa cista binarna datoteka treba da ima 'ORG 0h' umesto 'ORG 100h'.       

;--------------------------------------
; Relocirati i startovati EXE program
;--------------------------------------

RelocirajEXE:
        mov     ds, ax                  ; Segment pocetka EXE slike sa diska (sa zaglavljem): kod nas 60h

        add     ax, [ds:08h]            ; AX = dodaje se velicina zaglavlja u pragrafima (preskacemo zaglavlje)
        mov     cx, [ds:06h]            ; CX = broj relokacionih stavki
        mov     bx, [ds:18h]            ; BX = ofset pocetka RPT (Relocation Pointer Table)

        jcxz    KrajRelokacije          ; Preskoci Relociraj ako je broj relokacionih stavki = 0

Relociraj:                              
        mov     di, [ds:bx]             ; DI = ofset stavke u RPT       | Svaka stavka predstavlja memorijsku adresu  
        mov     dx, [ds:bx+2]           ; DX = segment stavke u RPT     | segmentne adrese koju treba relocirati
        add     dx, ax                  ; DX = na segement stavke dodati segment pocetka programa u memoriji

        push    ds
        mov     ds, dx                  
        add     [ds:di], ax             ; Izvrsiti promenu adrese segmenta na lokaciji stavke
        pop     ds

        add     bx, 4                   ; Sledeca stavka (stavke su DWORD)
        loop    Relociraj

KrajRelokacije:

        mov     bx, ax                  ; Informacije iz zaglavlja koje je upisao linker 
        add     bx, [ds:0Eh]            ; AX sadrzi segment pocetka izvrsnog koda
        mov     ss, bx                  ; Podeseni SS za EXE
        mov     sp, [ds:10h]            ; Inicijalni SP za EXE

        add     ax, [ds:16h]            ; Podeseni CS
        push    ax
        push    word [ds:14h]           ; Inicijalni IP
Run:
        mov     dl, [cs:bsDriveNumber]  ; Posledjujemo broj disk jedinice programu 
        sti                             ; koji startujemo, ako mu to zbog necega treba
        retf


; --------------------------------------------------------------------------
; FAT klasteri su deo sistema datoteka i oni ne obuhvataju boot sektor,
; sektore koji sadrze FAT tabele niti sektore koji sadrze root direktorijum.
; Klasteri se odnose samo na oblast podataka, koji mogu da budi bilo koja
; vrsta datoteke ili direktorijuma. 
; - FAT klasteri se aresiraju od 2 do n (0 i 1 se ne koriste).
; - LBA trazenog klastera racuna se ovako:
;   (trazeni_klaster - 2) * (broj_sektora_po_klasteru) + LBA_klastera_2
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------

;---------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Zbog istorijskih razloga (efikasnije iskoriscenje tadasnjeg dragocenog
; disk prostora i minimalno pomeranje glave diska), 12-bitne FAT stavke ne
; zauzimaju po 2 bajta (jednu celu 16-bitnu rec), vec se dele medju susednim
; bajtovima na sledeci nacin:
; - Ukoliko je klaster parni, koristiti donjih 12 bitova 16-bitne reci
; - Ukoliko je klaster neparni, koristiti gornjih 12 bitova 16-bitne reci
;
; Zbog toga je velicina FAT tabele 6KB, umesto 8KB 
; Racunica: FAT12 ima 2^12 stavki = 4096 = 4K
; --------  - Ako se svaka adresira sa 2 cela bajta 
;             (16 bitova od kojih se koristi samo 12 donjih) to je 2B*4K=8KB
;           - Ako se svaka stavka adresira sa tacno 12 bitova (1.5 bajtova)
;             to je onda 1.5B*4K=6KB       
;----------------------------------------------------------------------------

;---------------------------------
; Citanje FAT12 klastera    
;---------------------------------
; Ulaz:  ES:BX -> bafer
;        SI = broj klastera 
; Izlaz: SI = sledeci klaster
;        ES:BX -> sledeca adresa
;---------------------------------

CitajKlaster:
        mov     bp, sp

        lea     ax, [si-2]                 ; trazeni_klaster - 2
        xor     ch, ch
        mov     cl, [bpbSectorsPerCluster] ; CX = broj_sektora_po_klasteru         
        mul     cx                         ; (trazeni_klaster - 2) * (broj_sektora_po_klasteru)

        add     ax, [ss:bp+1*2]            ; DX:AX = LBA_trazenog_klastera =
        adc     dx, [ss:bp+2*2]            ; = (trazeni_klaster-2)*(broj_sektora_po_klasteru)+LBA_klastera_2

        call    CitajSektor                ; Kopirati sektor u bafer za datoteku

        mov     ax, [bpbBytesPerSector]
        shr     ax, 4                      ; AX = broj paragrafa po sektoru
        mul     cx                         ; AX = broj procitanih paragrafa za trazeni klaster  

        mov     cx, es
        add     cx, ax
        mov     es, cx                     ; ES:BX nova vrednost pointera bafera za datoteku

; --------------------------------------
; Deo karakteristican samo za FAT12
; Izlaz: SI = sledeci klaster datoteke
;---------------------------------------

        mov     ax, 3
        mul     si
        shr     ax, 1
        xchg    ax, si                    ; SI = klaster * 3 / 2 = klaster * 1.5

        push    ds
        mov     ds, [ss:bp+3*2]           ; DS = memorijski segment gde je smestena FAT              
        mov     si, [ds:si]               ; SI = broj sledeceg klastera iz FAT
        pop     ds

        jnc     CitajParniKlaster         ; Parni klaster prilikom mnozenja sa 1.5 nije imao ostatak

        shr     si, 4                     ; Postavljanje bitova iz neparnog klastera na pravo mesto (0..11)    
                                          ; Sada je sadrzaj SI sa istim vazecim bitovima i za parne i za neparne 
CitajParniKlaster:
        and     si, 0FFFh                 ; Osigurati da su vazeci bitovi na pozicijama od 0..11 (FAT12).
        ret

;---------------------------------------------------
; Citanje sektora upotrebom BIOS INT 13h, funkcija 2 
;---------------------------------------------------
; Ulaz:  DX:AX = LBA      
;        CX = broj sektora koje treba procitati
;        ES:BX -> adresa bafera     
; Izlaz: CF = 1 ako je nastala greska  
;---------------------------------------------------

;---------------------------------------------------
; Parametri koje zahteva BIOS INT 13h, funkcija 2
;---------------------------------------------------  
; AH = 2    (funkcija za citanje sektora)
; AL = broj sektora koje odjednom treba procitati
; CH = cilindar (donjih 8 od 10 bitova)
; CL = preostala dva bita cilindra + 6 bitova za sektor
; DH = glava
; DL = broj disk jedinice
; ES:BX = pointer na bafer gde se smestaju sektori
;----------------------------------------------------

;----------------------------------------------------------
; Konverzija iz LBA u CHS (Cylinder Head Sector):
;---------------------------------------------------------- 
; S = (LBA mod SPT) + 1
; H = (LBA / SPT) mod HPC
; C = (LBA / SPT) / HPC 
; gde su:
;           S - sektor
;           H - glava
;           C - cilindar 
;           SPT - broj sektora po stazi
;           HPC - broj glava po cilindru
;
; Neke BIOS verzije (Western Digital, Phoenix Technologies)
; poseduju tzv. INT 13h Extensions koje direktno rade sa LBA
; ----------------------------------------------------------


CitajSektor:
        pusha

SledeciSektor:
        mov     di, 5                   ; 5 pokusaja citanja

PokusajPonovo:
        pusha                           ; Cuvamo sve registre
        div     word [bpbSectorsPerTrack]    
                ; AX = LBA / SPT          Operacija div daje rezutat deljenja u AX, a ostatak u DX .
                ; DX = LBA mod SPT  = sektor - 1   
        mov     cx, dx
        inc     cx                      ; CX = sektor
        xor     dx, dx
        div     word [bpbHeadsPerCylinder]
                ; AX = (LBA / SPT) / HPC = cilindar               
                ; DX = (LBA / SPT) mod HPC = glava
                                        ; Cilindar se koduje sa 10 bitova, sektor sa 6 bitova
        mov     ch, al                  ; CH = LSB 0...7 od broja cilindra
        shl     ah, 6
        or      cl, ah                  ; CL = MSB 8...9 od broja cilindra + redni broj sektora

        mov     dh, dl                  ; DH = broj glave       
        mov     dl, [bsDriveNumber]     ; DL = broj diska     
        mov     ax, 201h                ; AL = ukupan broj sektora koje treba procitati               
                                        ; AH = 2 = funkcija za citanje
        int     13h                     ; Citaj sektor
        jnc     ZavrsenoCitanje         ; CF = 0 ako nema greske
                                        ; Nesto nije u redu. Resetovati disk.
        xor     ah, ah                  ; AH = 0 = reset funkcija
        int     13h                     

        popa
        dec     di
        jnz     PokusajPonovo           
        jmp     short GreskaGC

ZavrsenoCitanje:
        popa
        dec     cx
        jz      KrajCitanja             ; Poslednji sektor

        add     bx, [bpbBytesPerSector] ; Podesiti ofset u baferu za sledeci sektor
        add     ax, 1
        adc     dx, 0                   ; Podesiti LBA za sledeci sektor
        jmp     short SledeciSektor

KrajCitanja:
        popa
        ret

;--------------------
; Poruke o greskama
;--------------------

GreskaGC:
        mov     si, GreskaCitanja
        jmp     short Greska
GreskaNP:
        mov     si, NijePronadjen
Greska:
        mov     ah, 0Eh
        mov     bx, 7

        lodsb
        int     10h                    ; Prvi znak poruke o gresci
        lodsb
        int     10h                    ; Drugi znak poruke o gresci

        jmp     short $                ; Zavrsetak u beskonacnoj petlji :(

;-------------------
; String konstante
;-------------------
 GreskaCitanja      db      "GC"       ; Koristimo skracenice jer nemamo dovoljno prostora
 NijePronadjen      db      "NP"       ; za kompletne poruke unutar 512 bajtova boot sektora.
                                       ; Ovo se resava tako sto boot sektor ucita program "boot loader"
                                       ; koji moze da bude znatno veci od 512 bajtova. Npr., nas STARTUP.BIN
                                       ; moze da bude boot loader!
;------------------------------------------------
; Ispuniti peostali prostor boot sektora nulama
;------------------------------------------------

               times (512-13-($-$$)) db 0

;----------------------------------------------
; Ime programa kojeg treba ucitati i izvrsiti
;----------------------------------------------

ImePrograma     db      "STARTUP BIN"   ; Ime i ekstenzija datoteke moraju da budu dopunjeni
                                        ; praznim mestima (ukupno 11 bajtova, tacka se ne racuna)

;--------------------------
; ID za kraj boot sektora
;--------------------------

                dw      0AA55h
```

Compiler arguments: nasm -f bin -o BOOT12.SYS boot12.asm

P.S. Am I allowed to upload bins?

Comment: Your BPB has all the entries being filled by zeroes, but your professor has the entries filled in. This makes a difference because calculations are done in `main` with them. I can see you'd at least get a division by zero with `div     word [bpbBytesPerSector]`. What you need to do is fill in the BPB entries with something usable. Making it appear as 1 1.44MB floppy wouldn't be a bad start.

Comment: I have some sample BPB entries that would apply to a 1.44MB floppy disk in this other SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39238756/3857942

Comment: Honestly speaking, I have no idea how to do that... 

Will just putting same values as in his binary work? 

What confuses me more is that it seams like there is some data in his binary in different place than in my binary...

Comment: I thought something seemed vaguely familiar with your bootloader. Your professor seems to be using Alex Frunzes boot utilities (Alex is also an SO user who developed the smaller C compiler). It is possible your professor intended for you to use a special tool called mkimg144 that takes the bootloader you generated with NASM and then fills the fields in with parameters that look like a 1.44MB file.

Comment: You might want to look at this: https://github.com/alexfru/BootProg  . Especially the readme.txt file.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You helped me quite a bit!

Comment: I have got it to work by filling BPB...

Comment: Since this is more or less a duplicate of the other question regarding having a proper BPB I'm going to mark this as a duplicate. If my other SO answer helped you consider upvoting it.

Comment: I did vote it up. Thanks!